# Help with Double Sum (lattice sum) over all integers m,n of 1/(a+m^2+n^2)

Tags: summation, series-expansion

Im researching electric fields in periodic arrays of charges, and encountered this summation that I can't find any published work on.

Has anybody encountered a solution to $\sum_{m,n=-\infty,\infty}\frac{1}{a+m^2+n^2}$ where a is a real constant?

When constant a=0 it converges, see mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html.

The 1D version also converges, see the "Rational Functions" section of here: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#cite_note-7 Therefore I believe the 2D sum that this post focuses on will also converge.

Comment: This sum looks divergent. For large $m$ and $n$ we can approximate the sum by an integral: set $m=r\cos\phi$ and $n=r\sin\phi$, so that $m^2+n^2=r^2$ and the sum is approximately $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{a+r^2}2\pi r\,d r$, which diverges as $r\to\infty$.

Comment: The 1D sum converges, see the "Rational Functions" section of here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#cite_note-7

Therefore I believe the 2D sum will also converge.

Also, the 2D summation (without constant a) converges too, see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html

Comment: Yes it converges for dimension $d<2$, but not for $d\ge2$. The double sum you are linking does not converge: $\sum_{i,j=-\infty}^{\infty}'\frac{1}{(i^2+j^2)^s}=4\beta(s)\zeta(s)$ only works for $s>1$, not for your case $s=1$.

Comment: Thank you Roman!

Comment: As it stands (with all terms being positive) the summation diverges logaritmically, but you can get conditional convergence if you add a term (-1)^(m+n) in the numerator. The physical meaning of that term is that (as I suppose) the electric charges of the points in the lattice are of alternating signs (cations and anions)

Comment: You have a very interesting analysis of the electric field and potential created by a set of point charges allocated alternatingly in a 2D infinite square lattice in this link, take a look at it: [https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/12/6/1040/htm](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/12/6/1040/htm)

Comment: Many related problems are discussed in papers by David and Jonathan Borwein. See also "Lattice Sums Then and Now" (https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lattice-sums-then-and-now/)

Answer (score 14):

This kind of sum can be studied by integral transformation. Notice that $\int_0^1t^{x-1}dt=\frac{1}{x}$ if $\text{Re}(x)>0$:

```
Integrate[t^(x - 1), {t, 0, 1}]
(*    1/x if Re[x] > 0    *)
```

and therefore a $d$-dimensional lattice sum is
$$
S_d(a)=\sum_{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_d=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a+n_1^2+n_2^2+\ldots+n_d^2}=
\sum_{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_d=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_0^1 t^{a+n_1^2+n_2^2+\ldots+n_d^2-1}dt
= \int_0^1t^{a-1}\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}t^{n^2}\right)^ddt
$$

The infinite sum is [Jacobi's elliptic theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) $\vartheta_3(0,t)=\vartheta_3(t)$:

```
Sum[t^(n^2), {n, -∞, ∞}]
(*    EllipticTheta[3, 0, t]    *)
```

which makes the lattice sum
$$
S_d(a)= \int_0^1t^{a-1}\left[\vartheta_3(t)\right]^ddt
$$

```
S[d_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[t^(a - 1) EllipticTheta[3, t]^d, {t, 0, 1}]
```

This integral converges only for $d<2$ because the elliptic theta function is $\theta_3(t)\approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-t}}$ for $t\to1$:

```
Limit[Sqrt[1 - t] * EllipticTheta[3, t], t -> 1, Direction -> "FromBelow"]
(*    Sqrt[π]    *)
```

### more general denominator

For the more general sum
$$
S_{d,p}(a)=\sum_{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_d=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+n_1^2+n_2^2+\ldots+n_d^2)^p}
$$
we can use the integral relationship
$$
\int_0^1\frac{(-\ln t)^{p-1}}{\Gamma(p)}t^{x-1}dt=\frac{1}{x^p}
$$

```
Integrate[(-Log[t])^(p - 1)/Gamma[p] t^(x - 1), {t, 0, 1}]
(*    x^(-p) if Re[p] > 0 && Re[x] > 0    *)
```

Therefore,
$$
S_{d,p}(a)=\sum_{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_d=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_0^1\frac{(-\ln t)^{p-1}}{\Gamma(p)}t^{a+n_1^2+n_2^2+\ldots+n_d^2-1}dt\\
=\int_0^1 \frac{(-\ln t)^{p-1}}{\Gamma(p)} t^{a-1}\left[\vartheta_3(t)\right]^ddt
$$

```
S[d_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] /; d < 2*p && a > 0 := 
  NIntegrate[(-Log[t])^(p - 1)/Gamma[p] t^(a - 1) EllipticTheta[3, t]^d,
             {t, 0, 1}]
```

This integral converges for $d<2p$: as $t\to1^-$ we have $(-\ln t)\approx(1-t)$ and $\vartheta_3(t)\approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-t}}$, and so the integrand is asymptotically proportional to $(1-t)^{p-1-d/2}$; the integral converges if $p-1-d/2>-1$.

#### numerical stability

A note on convergence: the above numerical integral is rather difficult to evaluate for small $a\ll1$. To improve stability, we separate out the singular part of the integrand around $t\approx0$ by setting $\vartheta_3(t\approx0)\approx1$ and

```
J[d_, p_, a_, t_] = (-Log[t])^(p - 1)/Gamma[p] t^(a - 1) EllipticTheta[3, t]^d;
J0[d_, p_, a_, t_] = (-Log[t])^(p - 1)/Gamma[p] t^(a - 1);
```

The function `J0` carries the same singularity as the integrand `J` but can be integrated analytically:

```
Assuming[p > 0 && a > 0, Integrate[J0[d, p, a, t], {t, 0, 1}]]
(*    a^-p    *)
```

Therefore, the numerical integral can be written as

```
S1[d_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] /; d < 2*p && a > 0 && p > 0 :=
  a^-p + NIntegrate[J[d, p, a, t] - J0[d, p, a, t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

which can be evaluated for even very small values of $a$.

You are interested in the case $d=2$ and $p=3/2$:

```
Plot[S1[2, 3/2, a], {a, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice analysis of the problem. Does the integral converge for $d\in[1,2)$? Or only for $d=1$?

Comment: @Joe it converges for $d<2$, so $d\in(-\infty,2)$. Not sure what $d<0$ means in practice; but the integral seems fine with it.

Comment: Interesting. Does $\lim_{d\rightarrow 2^-}$ exist? That could be relevant to OP's physical problem, given that $S_2(a)$ is undefined

Comment: @Joe it diverges as $d\to2^-$.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if you can get anything interesting out of dimensional regularisation with $d=2-\epsilon$. I guess if the integral doesn't converge for any $d\ge 2$ then it doesn't look like there's a pole at $d=2$

Comment: @Joe for $d\to2^-$ we get $S_d(a)\approx\frac{2\pi}{2-d}$, independent of $a$. Looks like a pole to me.

Comment: @Roman Your derivations and explanations are powerful and clean -- big thank you! Seeing your proof of non-convergence caused me to look for an error in my derivation of the electrostatics that I was working with, and I found my error, which means that the sum I truly seek is $\sum_{all m,n}{\frac{1}{(a+m^2+n^2)^{3/2}}}$ and I think the exponent 3/2 causes the sum to converge.  Do you have similar capability to derive a converged closed form solution for this slightly different series?  If you like I can post it as a completely new question so everyone gets credit for working on it.

Comment: @dturn805 see update for general denominator powers.

Comment: @Roman, then you could expand $S_{2-\epsilon}(a)=\frac{2\pi}{\epsilon} + b(a) +O(\epsilon)$ and try to assign your physical meaning to $b(a)$, as is done in QFT. Looks like this is not what's needed though.

Comment: We indeed encounter such sums in QFT.  You must be very careful with your regulator to get something sensible, especially in 2D where you get logs rather than something that will be removed by dimensional regularization.  If you have a 2D square lattice with N items on a side, with periodic boundary conditions, you probably want $\left(\sum_{|m|,|n|\leq N/2} \frac{1}{n^2+m^2-x}\right)-2\pi \log(N/2)$; see eq 58 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.04425